# Regex pattern with 3 groups in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to understand regex in Python. I'm trying to trying this pattern:

```
string = re.sub(r'(\".+?\")(: )', '\"here!\": ', string)
```

for this kind of string:

```
{ some text "data": { "first": "xyz" some text}
```

I expected this to replace **"first": "xyz"** but to my surprise the string which is replaced is: **"data": { "first": "xyz"**. Why is that? I have no idea why is it working in such way.

Comment: This looks like some sort of `JSON`, why not use a parser in the first place?

Comment: @Jan that's because I am writing my custom parser tbh

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is matching the first portion of the input string surrounded by double quotes and followed by a colon, so it hits `"data"` before `"first"`.

I would go for a regular expression of:

```
'{\s*("\w+"):'
```

This will match the opening brace followed by some optional whitespace, then select the alphanumeric text in double quotes followed by a colon.

Also, you don't need to escape your double quotes as you are using a single quote as the delimiter for your regular expression.